# Set default app for .PDF file extension to Adobe or Edge?

Tags: powershell

My main goal is to print a `.PDF` file through PowerShell.

I can do that with the following line `Start-Process $Path -Verb Print`, so long as the user's default app for `.PDF` files is Adobe Acrobat.

So, in order to achieve printing from PowerShell, this is my intended script pseudocode:

```
- Get user's default app for .pdf
- Set user's default app for .pdf to Adobe Acrobat
- Print the .pdf file
- Set the user's default app for .pdf back to whatever they had it set to originally
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this. The closest I have gotten is the `ftype` Command Prompt command, but here is what I have witnessed that makes that not a solution:

When my default app is Adobe, print works. When my default app is Edge, print does not work, but the return from `ftype` is exactly the same as when my default was Adobe.

[image]

Does anyone know how to get/set default app through PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [DanySys's](https://github.com/DanysysTeam/PS-SFTA) `Set-FTA` (file type association) for this:

```
Set-FTA AcroExch.Document.DC .pdf
```

However, if you just want to print the files through adobe reader, try the command for that:

```
# Open and go straight to the print dialog
AcroRd32.exe /p <filename>
```

Comment: Thank you for the `AcroRd32` command. I did have to use the full path starting at C:\ since I guess Adobe isn't in my `PATH`, but nonetheless this is very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it appears that changing the default app for `.pdf` in the `Settings` will set values in

`Computer\HKEY_USERS\[USER-ID]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice`

So, here is a PowerShell script that gets the value for the user's set default app for `.PDF`

```
$User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:UserName)
$sid = $User.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
$key = "HKU:\${sid}\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.pdf\UserChoice"
if (Get-PSDrive HKU -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
} else {
    New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
}
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key).ProgId
```

This enables me to get the name of the default, and If I go into RegEdit, and remove the Deny permission of Set Value of the key for my user then I can set it, but by default the user's permission is denied for this key.

Comment: Brilliant. I am going to suppose that this may be applied to other extensions as well. Thank you.